# How to specify different match patterns for multiple content scripts in the manifest.json file of the same extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is the scenario:

**Scenario 1:**
I want to inject different content scripts into different pages based on the URL Domain.

For ex: Inject ***`cs1.js`*** content script into `www.a.com` but inject `cs2.js` content script into `www.b.com`.
Both the content scripts cs1.js and cs2.js are part of the same chrome extension.So how can I specify different match patterns ( under "matches" section while defining "content_scripts" in the manifest.json file ) so that one script is injected in one page while other is injected in other page.

**Scenario 2:**
How can I mention, if under a subdomain of say `www.a.com`, I wish to inject the content script into all pages in the domain **except** `www.b.a.com` ( all other subdomains need to be injected with the content script ). How do I specify match pattern for this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specifying the `content_scripts` within manifest.json is a bit limiting. Although you can specify different match patterns, you can only have it execute one possible slew of files.

To achieve what you want, you'll need to set up a `background_page` that can interpret page URLs, and execute content scripts as you see fit.

Three different methods might be:

1. Use the manifest's `content_scripts` to match all possible URLs and execute a simple content script to send a message request to the background page via [`chrome.extension.sendRequest()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest). The background page listens for messages with [`chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest), receives the message, interprets the tab's URL with `sender.tab.url` (or have the tab's message send `window.location.hostname`, probably easier), then decides what content scripts to inject to the tab via [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).
    
   or
2. Just have your `background_page` listen for [`chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated) and [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) to get a tab's URL, then decide what content scripts to inject to the tab via [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). No need to specify `content_scripts` in the manifest for this.
    
    
   or
3. Similar to 1, but have your manifest `content_scripts` script figure out what to do based on the current URL (again could interpret `window.location.hostname`), then use `chrome.extension.sendRequest()` with a message for your `background_page` stating which content scripts to execute (meaning your `background_page` doesn't decide - the original content script does). Same result though.

Comment: Actually, I'm incorrect. You *can* have different match matterns, and different scripts that execute. Just add another object to the `content_scripts` array, with a different set of `matches` and `js`, etc as needed.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot for the suggestions, were very helpful, specially the second answer ( adding another object to content_script ) .Worked perfectly.

Comment: Just had another ad-hoc question on chrome ext.. How can w access and manipulate the DOM of a (secure https) tab that has been created by the extension ( using chrome.tabs.create ) and how can I access the DOM of https pages within an iframe ( if it is posible, that is )..

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile szenario 1 can be solved:
You can inject different content scripts into different pages this way:

```
"content_scripts": 
[{
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "js": [
    "cs1.js"
  ],
  "matches": [
    "https://www.a.com/*"
  ]
},
{
  "run_at": "document_end",
  "js": [
    "cs2.js"
  ],
  "matches": [
    "https://www.b.com/*"
  ]
}],
```

Hope this answear helps for the initial question.

Comment: *This* is the correct answer, the other answers are wrong or dead

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#include-exclude-globs

Does this help at all?

Comment: It does help but would be very nice if you could compile the important parts here. Thanks!